# Accessing and disabling nested swipers (SwiperJS)

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have a layout with nested swipers, pretty much exactly the same as in the demo. Parent and child swipers have different parameters and they are separated like this:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    ... parameters,
}
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
    ... parameters,
}
```

By toggling a button I want to disable both swipers simultaneously. So far I was able to disable only the parent swiper with a function that contains: `swiper.disable(swiper);`
To disable child swipers I tried `swiper2.disable()`, and `swiper.disable(swiper2)`, but that didn't work. What is the proper way of accessing nested swipers?

Thanks for the help.

---

A minimal reproducible example putted in proper stack snippet throws a `ReferenceError`. But the same code works when uploaded as a .html file to a server, and console in Chromium is not giving any errors or warnings about it.

[image]

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.overlay-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay-hide {
    display: none;
}
.overlay-show {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;
    z-index: 5;
}
.swiper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
.swiper-slide {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper2 mySwiper2">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="overlay-button" onclick="toggleOverlay(event)"></div>
                            <div class="overlay-hide">OVERLAY CONTENT</div>
                            <div class="">MAIN SLIDE CONTENT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="overlay-button" onclick="toggleOverlay(event)"></div>
                            <div class="overlay-hide">OVERLAY CONTENT</div>
                            <div class="">MAIN SLIDE CONTENT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="overlay-button" onclick="toggleOverlay(event)"></div>
                            <div class="overlay-hide">OVERLAY CONTENT</div>
                            <div class="">MAIN SLIDE CONTENT</div>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper2 mySwiper2">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="overlay-button" onclick="toggleOverlay(event)"></div>
                            <div class="overlay-hide">OVERLAY CONTENT</div>
                            <div class="">MAIN SLIDE CONTENT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="overlay-button" onclick="toggleOverlay(event)"></div>
                            <div class="overlay-hide">OVERLAY CONTENT</div>
                            <div class="">MAIN SLIDE CONTENT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="overlay-button" onclick="toggleOverlay(event)"></div>
                            <div class="overlay-hide">OVERLAY CONTENT</div>
                            <div class="">MAIN SLIDE CONTENT</div>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
    //~ VERTICAL SWIPER
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        direction: "vertical",
        mousewheel: true,
    });
    //~ HORIZONTAL SWIPER
    var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
    });
    
    function toggleOverlay(event) {
        
        var overlay = event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        
        if (overlay.classList.contains("overlay-hide")){
            overlay.classList.remove("overlay-hide");
            overlay.classList.add("overlay-show");
            swiper.disable();
        }
        else if (overlay.classList.contains("overlay-show")){
            overlay.classList.remove("overlay-show");
            overlay.classList.add("overlay-hide");
            swiper.enable();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mre]?

Comment: Thank you. Will do it, but it will take me some time.

Comment: @HuyPhạm I edited the question.